# TypeError: schemaInstance[direction] is not a function

Tags: adonis.js

Less of a question and more of an answer. Using AdonisJS and I got this after running: adonis migration:refresh

The issue was that I didn't have the down method defined.

down () {

}

Answer (score 1):

when you refresh the table then required **down** method because when you revert changes then down method use so more [info](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/migrations#_down) view documents